# Can I use firebase as a backend for flutter desktop app? If so how?

Tags: firebase, flutter-desktop

I am building a desktop app using flutter. Can I use firebase as a backend for that? If so how?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in the official flutterfire desktop. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!

https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte

Answer (score 5):

If you check the Firebase documentation on the [available plugins](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#available-plugins) there's a table exactly describing which ones also work (in beta) on macOS:

[image]

If you want to go beyond macOS, also see:

- [Flutter:How can we use Firebase database with desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743910/flutterhow-can-we-use-firebase-database-with-desktop-application)
- [How to integrate flutter windows app with firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69221292/how-to-integrate-flutter-windows-app-with-firebase)
- [cloud Firestore connect my flutter windows app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61940229/cloud-firestore-connect-my-flutter-windows-app)
- [Is there anyway to use firebase storage for flutter desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076570/is-there-anyway-to-use-firebase-storage-for-flutter-desktop)

Most of these point to using the REST APIs of the various Firebase products.

Answer (score 1):

Officially it supports only on macOs, it doesn't support on windows.
You can use firedart package Click [here](https://pub.dev/packages/firedart) to use firebase on windows.